# Shell program in C has odd fork behaviour

Tags: c, linux, shell, fork

I am writing a C program to emulate a simple shell. This shell will basically evaluate commands like any other shell (ls, cat, etc.), as well as handle pipelining and redirection.

Currently, I am trying to start out by getting user input, tokenizing it, and executing the command provided (e.g. executing only "ls" and not "ls -l"). However, I am having a lot of difficulty with the forking. It seems that every time I fork, something goes wrong and hundreds of identical processes are created, leading to my computer freezing and me having to restart. The code appears to be correct, but I have no idea what is causing this behaviour. Below is the relevant portion of my code (main method and input tokenizer method).

```
int main() {
    char inputLine[512];    //user input
    char *args[10];         //arguments
    char* pathVar = "/bin/";//path for argument
    char programPath[512];  //pathVar + args[0]
    int n;                  //count variable

    //loop
    while (1) {
        //print prompt, get input
        printf("input> ");
        fgets(inputLine, 512, stdin);
        n = tokenizer(inputLine, args);

        //fork process
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if (pid != 0) {     //if parent
            wait(NULL);
        } else {            //if child
            //format input for execution
            strcpy(programPath, pathVar);
            strcat(programPath, args[0]);

            //execute user command
            int returnVal = execv(programPath, args);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int tokenizer(char *input, char *args[]) {
    char *line;             //current line
    int i = 0;              //count variable

    line = input;
    args[i] = strtok(line, " ");
    do {
        i++;
        line = NULL;
        args[i] = strtok(line, " ");
    } while (args[i] != NULL);

    return i;
}
```

Comment: What does "goes wrong" mean? Have you tried it with something simpler in the exec -- or replacing the exec -- to isolate the problem? Have you tried printing out programPath to make sure it is what you think it should be?

Comment: I have made sure that the tokenizing, etc. works before trying to implement the exec. The user input is properly tokenized (arguments are separated by spaces) and the program path is correctly formed (e.g. "/bin/ls"). The big problem seems to be with the forking.

Comment: you execute commands in child process that doesn't write on console

Comment: There seems to be nothing in the code you've shown that would cause what you describe.

Comment: Actually, you should be testing the return value of `fork` for an error (-1), and you should also `exit` after the `execv` just in case it fails (although saving its return value is useless since if it succeeds it doesn't return and if it fails it always returns -1).

Comment: Really? Hmm, strange. When I ran this code on my computer, it created hundreds of processes and messed up my day. Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try implementing those then.

Comment: The one thing I noticed is that because `fgets` leaves the newline in the string and you aren't parsing it out you are trying to `exec` something like "ls\n".  That appears to have sent my system into a dizzy as well.  I'm not exactly sure *what* my system was doing but the disk starting thrashing like crazy and I could never get control of the system before I brought it down hard.  I headed for some sleep but if you haven't solved it and I am feeling courageous I'll look at it again in the morning.

Comment: @Duck Good one! @user41419 You can most easily fix the problem Duck discovered by adding newline to your `strtok` delimiters.

Comment: Well the `execv` is no doubt failing and the child(ren) may then be looping but I am not sure why all the children get past the fgets again.  Too tired to think about it now.

Comment: Study the source code of existing free software shells (`sash` or `bash`). Also `strace` them. Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting it all together:
You need to check `fork` and `execv` for failure.
You should `exit` after an `execv` failure (and perhaps after a `fork` failure).
And you need to add `\n` to the `strtok` delimiters (or remove the newline from the input line in some other way).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAXARGS 10
#define PATH "/bin/"

int main() {
    char inputLine[BUFSIZ];
    char *args[MAXARGS];
    char programPath[BUFSIZ + sizeof(PATH) + 10];

    while (1) {
        printf(":-> ");
        if (fgets(inputLine, BUFSIZ, stdin) == NULL) /* ctrl-D entered */
            break;

        tokenize(inputLine, args);

        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (pid != 0) {  /* parent */
            wait(NULL);

        } else {         /* child */
            strcpy(programPath, PATH);
            strcat(programPath, args[0]);

            execv(programPath, args); /* will not return unless it fails */

            perror("execv");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int tokenize(char *input, char *args[]) {
    int i = 0;

    args[0] = strtok(input, " \n");
    for (i = 0; args[i] && i < MAXARGS-1; ++i)
        args[++i] = strtok(NULL, " \n");

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked wonderfully! No more frustration or restarting.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that **execv** doesn't fail and also be sure to **exit()** at the end of the child block.

```
            //execute user command
            int returnVal = execv(programPath, args);

            // check return from execv
            if (returnVal < 0) {
                perror("execv");
                exit(1);
            }
```

Also, beware using functions like **strcpy** in this context since they may lead to buffer overflows. If an untrusted attacker type is talking to your shell this type of security issue could let them break out of the "sandbox".

Comment: There is no point in capturing the return value of `execv()`. If it is succeeds, it does not return; if it returns, it failed. It is a very good idea to put an error message and an exit after the failed `execv()`.  It just doesn't need to be in conditional code.

Comment: Fair enough Jonathan. Also, hi! Hope all is well with you.